# DHIS2 - Choose file button won't appear when assigning the “file” type to a data element

Tags: dhis-2

On the event capture screen, when selecting a program that contains data of type "file" it will be displayed as a text field instead of a choose file button, I tried changing this behavior creating a custom form but looks like this option gets ignored. Is there any way to change this behavior?

Comment: You might have to clear your Web browser cache completely to make it appear. Which version of DHIS 2 are you running?

Comment: It was a bug of a past dhis version, it was fixed already, but thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug of a past dhis version, it was fixed already.